# Adding a list of views in backbone correctly

Tags: backbone.js

Currently when I insert a list of views in backbone I do :

```
    var jqGuestList = $("#guestList");
    jqGuestList.empty();

    items.each(function(item){
        var view = new wedapp.view.GuestItem({
            model: item,
            collection: this.collection
        });

        jqGuestList.append(view.render().el);
    });
```

This however cause my a great deal of pain, adding each one manually to the DOM is slow as hell, specially on mobile but even on desktop..

is there a way to insert all the views in one jqGuestList.html(views) instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a Document Fragment http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

```
var jqGuestList = $("#guestList");
jqGuestList.empty();

var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
items.each( function(item) {
    var view=new wedapp.view.GuestItem({model:item});
    frag.appendChild(view.render().el);
});

jqGuestList.append(frag);
```

You should see some improvement.

Comment: Yea I was wondering about those, is it really faster than adding to the dom directly if you saved the node?

Comment: reading from the doc it seems it will only trigger only one reflow from the browser, definitely a big improvement

Comment: Some interesting discussion about this. I've been wondering the benefits myself. [Does using a document fragment really improve performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203196/does-using-a-document-fragment-really-improve-performance)

Comment: @orangewarp The key is to work with a detached node to avoid browser reflows. Fragments will do, but you could also use a new jQuery object or a node you explicitly detached.