# Build DOM elements from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a JSON string that takes this form...

```
{
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "person1",
            "description": "This is a brief description of my service.",
            "image": "mandg1.jpg",
            "type": "first",
            "insured": "yes",
            "license": "N\/A",
            "picture": "mandg1.jpg",
            "yearsinbusiness": "8",
            "distance": 15
        },
        {
            "name": "person2",
            "description": "This is a brief description of my service.",
            "image": "mandg2.jpg",
            "type": "second",
            "insured": "yes",
            "license": "N\/A",
            "picture": "mandg2.jpg",
            "yearsinbusiness": "8",
            "distance": 19
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'd like to do is, via jQuery, build a group of divs based upon the "people" key...so in the instance above...you'd end up creating 2 elements...and append them to the div id="container".  If there were 50 elements, you'd end up with 50 divs, etc etc etc.

```
 <div id="container">
 <div id="person1">
 <p>Name: person1</p>
 <p>Description: This is a brief description of my service</p>
 </div>
 <div id="person2">  
 <p>Name: person2</p> 
 <p>Description: This is a brief description of my service</p>
 </div> 
 </div>
```

What would the jQuery syntax for that be?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a basic loop and build the elements yourself. Tip: Store the new DOM elements as HTML strings in a JavaScript array, `.join` them into a single string, and append them all to the page *at once* for greater efficiency.

Comment: You'd need to loop through the JSON and using keys and values make the elements. This isn't exactly what you want but look at this link https://github.com/Script47/Form.js I used JavaScript object array to build forms, I'm sure with a little bit of work you can adapt it to make it fit your purpose.

Comment: @Blazemonger An alternative would be to use a document fragment, if you want to create real com objects in the first place. Sometimes that's the easier approach, when you want to add events, too.

Comment: @Sirko [Also good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203196/does-using-a-document-fragment-really-improve-performance) -- jQuery doesn't really automate the process of working with document fragments, [but it's not that difficult, either](http://jsfiddle.net/hc5ED/6/).

Comment: Sounds like a perfect case for the [`<template>`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/) tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a great opportunity to learn to use the power of templates (in the below code example, I use the tim library available here: https://github.com/premasagar/tim) It simply maps an object's properties to `{{propertyname}}` in your template.

```
var tmpl = '<div id="person-{{name}}">\
 <p>Name: {{name}}</p>\
 <p>Description: {{description}}</p>\
 </div>';

var json = ... //your json object
var html = '';
$.each(json.people,function(i,person) { html += tim(tmpl,person); });
$('#someelement').html(html);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with jQuery only. You wrote your json was "a string", but if already an object you can ofcourse omit the parseJSON part.

```
var json = '{"people...';
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
var markupList = $.map(data.people, function (val, i) { return '<div id="' + val.name + '"><p>Name: ' + val.name + '</p><p>Description: ' + val.description + '</p></div>'; });
$(markupList).appendTo('#container');
```