# Document fragment vs `div` container

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've searched through stackoverflow questions and found few questions about the same topic, but none of them has an extensive answer I'm looking for. Most answers are focused around performance, but I'm looking for other differences as well.  Basically, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203196/does-using-a-document-fragment-really-improve-performance) sums up the question succinctly:

> if I create an element (a  for example) in a variable but DO NOT
>   APPEND IT TO THE DOM, add elements (divs, tables, etc ) and stuff and
>   after all the work has been done (loops, validations, styling of
>   elements), that element is appended, is it the same as a fragment?

I've decided to give it a shot once again and see if anyone can give a good answer.

So, why would I want to use this:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var divContainer = document.createElement("div");
var divHeader = document.createElement("div");
divContainer.appendChild( divHeader );
fragment.appendChild( divContainer );
document.getElementById("someElement").appendChild( fragment.cloneNode(true) );
```

instead of this:

```
var divContainer = document.createElement("div");
var divHeader = document.createElement("div");
divContainer.appendChild( divHeader );
document.getElementById("someElement").appendChild( divContainer );
```

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I've updated my questions with `Most answers are focused around performance, but I'm looking for other differences as well.`

Comment: it's not the same since the fragment doesn't exist in the DOM, or I missed the question

Comment: What is the question? What differences are you looking for? An element not added to the DOM is only a variable in memory and not rendered by the browser. What else do you want to know?

Comment: I think you should post your own question about the doubt you have.

Comment: @CharlieH, updated the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both methods are largely the same, as they can both be used to store elements without modifying the DOM immediately. There are a few catches though.

## Differences:

- A `div` has the prototype chain `HTMLDivElement - HTMLElement - Element - Node - EventTarget`, whereas a `document-fragment` has `DocumentFragment - Node - EventTarget`. This means a `div` has more methods and properties available (like `innerHTML`).
- When appending a `div` to the DOM, the whole element is inserted, the variable still references to the element. Appending a `document-fragment` inserts all its contents, leaving the variable to reference an empty fragment.

## Usage `document-fragment`:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var div1 = document.createElement('div');
var div2 = document.createElement('div');
var div3 = document.createElement('div');

fragment.appendChild(div1);
fragment.appendChild(div2);
div2.appendChild(div3);              //fragment now contains the sub-tree

document.body.appendChild(fragment); //fragment is now an empty document-fragment, and is not in the DOM.
```

Result:

```
<body>
    <div></div>       <!--div1-->
    <div>             <!--div2-->
         <div></div>  <!--div3-->
    </div>
</body>
```

## Usage `div`:

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
var div1 = document.createElement('div');
var div2 = document.createElement('div');
var div3 = document.createElement('div');

container.appendChild(div1);
container.appendChild(div2);
div2.appendChild(div3);               //container is now a div with the sub-tree inside.

document.body.appendChild(container); //container is still the div with the sub-tree, but is now in the DOM.
```

Result:

```
<body>
    <div>                 <!--container-->
        <div></div>       <!--div1-->
        <div>             <!--div2-->
             <div></div>  <!--div3-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

## In short:

- Use an `element` if you only want to insert one element (with other elements *inside* it).
- Use an `element` if you want to parse html in text format using innerHTML.
- Use a `document-fragment` if you want to insert multiple *adjacent* elements.

Comment: I think the question is more about speed. This applies to things like dynamically creating lists that require a list wrapper. If you just say `var ul = document.createElement('ul');` `for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li')) }` `document.body.appendChild(ul)`, that should actually be minuscully better than creating frag, appending `li` to frag, appending frag to ul then finally appending ul to body.

Comment: @cowbert, true. That's because you're only appending to the DOM _once_. It would be a different scenario when the `<ul>` is already present in the DOM.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the answer.