# Why isn't using a document fragment way better for performance when appending multiple elements to the DOM

Tags: javascript, performance

First of all, this is not the same as this question, although you may think it is as first glance: [Does using a document fragment really improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203196/does-using-a-document-fragment-really-improve-performance)

See: this js fiddle https://jsperf.com/fragment-no-clone

If you are creating a bunch of new nodes in a loop with the intention of appending them to the DOM, in my MIND it is way faster to first create a fragment, append those elements to the fragment, and then append the fragment to the DOM *after* everything is set up. (as opposed to creating an element, append to DOM, create the next element, append to DOM, one after the other)

Here is a bit of code just to illustrate what I mean:

**Using a Fragment**

```
let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  let element = document.createElement('div');
  fragment.appendChild(element);
}

document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

**Not using a Fragment**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  let element = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

The reason why I think the fragment should be faster is because my understanding of how browsers work: If I'm just appending elements one after the other *immediately* then the browser has to do way more painting and calculating, whereas if I set it up nicely in a fragment and then append everything all at once, the browser only has to paint/calculate *once*

HOWEVER.

I am not really seeing that kind of performance gain in reality. Testing Chrome/Safari on that fiddle the difference is negligible, and while in Firefox there is a small boost in favour of using a fragment, it's nothing huge.

So what's happening under the hood? Is my understanding totally flawed?

Comment: `See: this js fiddle https://jsperf.com/fragment-no-clone` a document fragment is nearly twice as fast for me on Firefox.

Comment: @vlaz ooo nice so maybe my gut is correct after all

Comment: what I'm seeing is that NOT using a fragment is faster in chrome/safari but only by a tiny bit, not enough to really mean anything. They're basically neck-and-neck.

Comment: Just to let you know - I wrote that comment as I started reading the question. I then ran the test in Chrome and finished reading the question. Had to wait for a bit, as Chrome hadn't finished. In chrome, the difference was pretty small and even though the second approach was faster, that was by around a percent. BOTH were a lot slower than FF, though - in FF using the fragment the speed reported was ~450 ops per second, the direct approach was ~200 ops/sec. In Chrome, by comparison both were ~120-130.

Comment: I think the test would show different results for complex DOM nodes being inserted - what I mean is nodes that will have CSS styles applied to them that could potentially have to re-fit items in containers which would be a more complex reflow each time. A document fragment should minimise the impact of these.

Comment: @vlaz Oh really good point that I hadn't thought of, thank you. That's probably the answer. Maybe I'll try putting together a test to confirm!

Comment: Actually, I was looking at that other question you mentioned and noticed something in the comments to the accepted answer: `he jsPerf test here does not incorporate page reflows` I suspected that might be the case - I didn't think it actually puts your data in some DOM that's displayed. If it's in something like an iframe that is hidden, it wouldn't reflow. So, perhaps a more accurate test is to make an HTML page and re-try both approaches using the developer performance measuring tools.

Comment: The DOM is just a js object. So your two tests should indeed not show too much difference (only up to js optimizer). No, the browser doesn't have to repaint, nor to do a reflow at every changes in the DOM. In best case, they will do it only once (generally just before the next screen refresh). However, [some DOM methods will force a reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a), and if you do call one of these methods in your loop, then you'll see an huge difference.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, I just spent a bit of time playing with it and that does indeed seem to be the case. I knew about how some methods will force a reflow but I thought for some reason that making any changes to the DOM would have similar side effects - why else would react use a "shadow dom" for example. I'd love for a detailed breakdown if someone wants to answer but I'm also thinking about just spending some more time researching myself and answering my own question, ha.